# Include Page for every No. of Div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, google-apps-script

Good Morning. I have a code here that displays data in every loop.

```
<script>
function LoadAllData(){
google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(GenerateMainTable).getData();
}
function GenerateMainTable(data) {
  var createcard = document.getElementById("maincontainer");
  createcard.innerHTML += '<div class="container" width = "100%" >' 

  for (var i = 1; i < data.length; i++) {
    var imagelink = data[i][0],
        brand =  data[i][1],
        prodcat = data[i][2],
        prodcode = data[i][3],
        prodname = data[i][4],
        packaging = data[i][5],
        srp = data[i][6] ,
        des1 = data[i][7],
        des2 = data[i][8],
        des3 = data[i][9],
        des4 = data[i][10],
        des5 = data[i][11],
        des6 = data[i][12];

    if (data[i][0] === "") { break; }
    createcard.innerHTML += '<div class="card">' +                                      
                            '<div id="one">' +
                            '<img class = "tableformat" src="' + imagelink + '" alt="Product" height="94%" width="94%" align = "center">' +
                            '</div>' +
                            '<div id="two">'+
                             '<table width = "100%" height = "100%" class = "tableformat">' +
'   <tbody>' +
'       <tr class = "tableformat">' +
'           <td class = "tableformat">Product Description</td>' +
'           <td class = "tableformat">SRP</td>' +
'           <td class = "tableformat">Packaging</td>' +
'       </tr>' +
'       <tr class = "tableformat">' +
'           <td class = "tableformat">' + prodcode + '</td>' +
'           <td class = "tableformat">' + srp + '</td>' +
'           <td class = "tableformat">' + packaging + '</td>' +
'       </tr>' +
'       <tr class = "tableformat">' +
'           <td  colspan="3" class = "tableformat">'+ des1 +'</td>' +
'       </tr>' +
'       <tr class = "tableformat">' +
'           <td  colspan="3" class = "tableformat">'+ des2 +'</td>' +
'       </tr>' +
'       <tr class = "tableformat">' +
'           <td  colspan="3" class = "tableformat">'+ des3 +'</td>' +
'       </tr>' +
'       <tr class = "tableformat">' +
'           <td  colspan="3" class = "tableformat">'+ des4 +'</td>' +
'       </tr>' +
'       <tr class = "tableformat">' +
'           <td  colspan="3" class = "tableformat">'+ des5 +'</td>' +
'       </tr>' +
'       <tr class = "tableformat">' +
'           <td  colspan="3" class = "tableformat">'+ des6 +'</td>' +
'       </tr>' +
'   </tbody>' +
'</table>'
                            '</div>' +  
                            '</div>'; 
  }
  createcard.innerHTML += '</div>';
}
</script>
```

by using the css below it will look like a card based on image below.

```
<style>
   .card {
          box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
          transition: 0.3s;
          width: 49%;
          height: 206px;
          display:inline-block;
          margin-left: 7px;
          margin-bottom: 20px;
        }

         .card:hover {
          box-shadow: 0 8px 16px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
        }
   div#one {
          width: 30%;
          height: 100%;
          float: left;
        }
   div#two {
          margin-left: 30%;
          height: 100%;
   }
   * {
          font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
          font-size: 12px;
   }     
   .tableformat{
          border:1px solid #ddd;
          border-collapse: collapse;
          padding: 5px;
          text-align:left;
    }
    .img{
         display: block;
         margin: auto;
    }

body {
    font-family: arial;
}
select {
    border: 1px solid #d6d8db;
    background-color: #ecedee;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #47515c;
    padding: 12px 30px 12px 10px;
    width: 300px;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
select > option {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    padding: 5px 0px;
}
.customSelect {
    border: 1px solid #d6d8db;
    background-color: #ecedee;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #47515c;
    padding: 12px 10px 12px 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.customSelect.changed {
    background-color: #f0dea4;
}   
.customSelectInner {
    background:url(http://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/cc_mono_icon_set/blacks/16x16/br_down.png) no-repeat center right;
}

    .simple-input {

    border: 0px solid #F1B720;
    color: #333;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.simple-input:hover {
    border-radius: 8px
}

.simple-input:focus {
    outline: none;
    border-radius: 8px;
    border-color: #EBD292;
}
</style>
```

How what if my data has reach many rows? so the cards will display all the way down. So I have an idea here that looks hard for me. How can I include paging? like

```
<< 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 >>
```

create a page for every 10 cards and if the last one did not made 10 cards then also create div. Thats my problem .TYSM

by the way here is the ouput.

[image]

**Updated**

and here is where I get the data

```
function getData() {
  return SpreadsheetApp
         .openById('1NH4g8gmFiWVUqKPxrxERWuK6uUyz8ItkCrzK9q6B5J8').getSheetByName('Product List').getDataRange().getValues();
   return htmlTemplate;
}
```

Comment: Please clarify the question a little better. Thank you.

Comment: If you are wondering how to include paging there are a number of [jQuery paging libraries](https://www.google.com/search?q=jquery+paging) available.

Comment: @Difster My target here is to create a page for every 10 Divs(Card) created instead of displaying them all the waiy down.

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify the method google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(GenerateMainTable).getData(); and pass some pagination parameters, I don't know how your function is set up but I imagine at every click at the pagination will call the method above containing the parameters necessary to get the correct data.

Would be something like this:

google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(GenerateMainTable).getData( 2 );
whereas 2 is the second item of the pagination ( Page 2 ).

Comment: Your answer means something to me I will update my post so you can understand more.